# Manipulate big Textfiles in Java

Tags: java, text, nio

I was wondering how do you manipulate big Textfiles in Java, if we assume that the Filesize is larger than the memory. I googled that topic and it shows that most people recommend `java.nio`for such a task.

Unfortunately I haven't found any documentation on how to manipulate the File. For example read every Line, modify it, write it. I tried something like this, but this doesn't work:

```
    FileChannel fileChannel = null;
    try {
        fileChannel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(256);

        while (fileChannel.read(buffer) != -1) {
            buffer.rewind();
            buffer.flip();
            String nextLine = buffer.asCharBuffer().toString();
            if (replaceBackSlashes) {
                nextLine = nextLine.replace("\\\\", "/");
            }
            if (!(removeEmptyLines && StringUtils.isEmpty(nextLine))) {
                buffer.flip();
                buffer.asCharBuffer().put(nextLine);
            }

            buffer.clear();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fileChannel != null) {
            try {
                fileChannel.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

So what are your recommendations? Also the String `nextline`, doesn't match anything in my File. Maybe I need to set the encoding?

Comment: How large a text file are we talking here? If you're only working on a single line at a time, why not just use a BufferedReader to read a line, modify it, and write it to a BufferedWriter. Memory use is constant (only one line is in memory at any time), plus some buffers in the reader and writer.

Comment: Do not modify the file inline! What do you think will happen if you write a line longer than the previous one? Write the modifications in another file and only then rename to the original file. All text editors do that.

Comment: @PhilippReichart The Files can grow up to several `GB`. Thank you for the tip on the BufferedReader and Writer. I will try this.

Comment: @fge Thank you, but I was hoping to get around this. I was hoping this would be possible with the use of a `RandomAccessFile`? Is this the common behavior of Texteditors? Do you have any links for that statement? I think Texteditors would do it really inline.

Comment: @Robin whatever way you access the file, the OS will not magically extend and/or shrink the file for you. As to links, I don't have any, I just `watch -n 1 ls -Al`.

Comment: @Robin That can't work. Imagine how your text file is laid out on your hard drive. If you overwrite a line with a longer one, it will spill over and overwrite the beginning of the next line. Conversely, if you overwrite a line with a shorter one, the rest of the old one will remain. You can only do in-place overwrites if you have a fixed line width, accept whitespace at the end and don't insert/delete lines. Every other solution would have to move the rest of the file back by a few bytes when you extend a line, which would be unbelievably slow. That's why you write your edits to a new file.

Comment: @fge Ok thank you, I think I will delete all my written code and just write it new with BufferedReader and Writer

Comment: @us2012 I think you are right. Probably I was just to blind to get this. Thank you

Comment: 'I googled that topic and it shows that most people recommend java.nio for such a task.' It shouldn't. The correct approach is line by line. People seem to think that NIO solves all kinds of problems it wasn't aimed at.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Line by line. Something like this ...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File someFile = new File("someFile.txt");
    File temp = File.createTempFile(someFile.getName(), null);
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    PrintStream writer = null;

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(someFile));
        writer = new PrintStream(temp);

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null) {
            // manipulate line
            writer.println(line);
        }
    }
    finally {
        if (writer!=null) writer.close();
        if (reader!=null) reader.close();
    }
    if (!someFile.delete()) throw new Exception("Failed to remove " + someFile.getName());
    if (!temp.renameTo(someFile)) throw new Exception("Failed to replace " + someFile.getName());
}
```

Comment: Note! You need to check for the return code of `.renameTo()` since it "fails silently" (returns false if rename fails). `java.io.File` sucks.

Comment: If all your `catch` block does is rethrow, you can just use a `try-finally` construct and leave out the catch block completely :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your work. I am currently writing the same code :D. Now I can copy paste some pieces. Also +1 For the 1 line if statements in the `finally` block. I never thought about that, but I like it. Also I think we should delete the original file(someFile in your code) first?

Answer (score 2):

Kudos to xagyg for a [nice, clean answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14215864/180740)! The following just didn't fit into a comment:

If you're running Java 7 already, you can save a lot of boilerplate code by using [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for the processing loop:

```
File source = ...
File target = ...
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(source));
     PrintStream out = new PrintStream(target)) {
  String line;
  while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    // manipulate line
    out.println(line);
  }
}
// no catch or finally clause!
```

No more of that `initalize-to-null-try-catch-finally-close-if-not-null` mess, Java will take care of that for you now. Less code, less potential to forget or screw up that crucial call to `close()`.

Comment: The BufferedReader is already in there, just replace the PrintWriter line with some `BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(...)`. Take a look at the try-with-resources article I linked in the answer, it explains the syntax in detail.

Comment: Thanks again. I was to fast with writing my comment. I already saw it.

Comment: Note that if you switch from `PrintStream` to `BufferedWriter` you have to output line endings yourself: there's no `writeln` method on `BufferedWriter` like `PrintWriter`'s `println` method. Otherwise your output file will be one long line.

Comment: Thank you again, but just went with the PrintStream. I didn't know about this Class but it seems pretty nice as far as I can see this right now.